# Ng-repeat and Native scrolling creating issue with scope loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating hybrid application and i am facing issue in ng-repeat with native scrolling.

Below are my template file code

```
<ion-view align-title="center"> 
<ion-content class="ionic headerWithNav" overflow-scroll='true'> 
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="lessondata in AllLessonComing" ng-class="{true: 'showBg', false: ''}[(AllLessonComing).length>0]" ng-click="lessondetailsPage('{{lessondata.id}}')">
      <div class="lesson-wrap">
        <div class="lesson-img">
          <div class="lession-price"> <span>{{lessondata.price}}</span> </div>
          <div class="lessonImg-wrap"><img image-lazy-src="{{lessondata.image}}" lazy-scroll-resize="true" image-lazy-loader="bubbles" class="ink" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="lessonInfo">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-67">
              <h1>{{lessondata.title}}</h1>
              <div class="lesson-status">{{lessondata.category_name}}</div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col lesson-location">{{lessondata.City}}</div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="lesson-rating"><img src="img/start-rating.jpg"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col padr-none">
              <div class="trainnerImg-wrap">
                <div class="trainee-img"> <img src="{{lessondata.coach_image}}"> </div>
                <div class="trainee-name">{{lessondata.coach_name}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

     <li ng-show="(AllLessonComing).length == 0">
            <div class="inner-container"><div class="no-results">No Lesson Found</div></div>
     </li>
</ul>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

As you can see i am  using "overflow-scroll='true'" for native scrolling and ng-repeat for the showing my lessons.

This is an image when scope data render first time--
[when scope data render first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Iht.png)

And this is an image when i scroll speedily  [when i scroll speedily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3brv2.png)

ISSUE:- **I don't know why these images and text are reloading or flickering when i scroll speedily**

Answer (score 1):

My Code is correct.

ng-repeat was creating issue with the ionic 1.0. Now ionic released new version that is ionic 1.2 and you will see that this issue has been resolved by ionic's developers.

you can update your ionic version easily.

If you are using NPM then use this command

```
ionic lib update
```

Check brower.JSON file in www/lib/ionic/ folder. if brower.JSON exists then remove this file.

you will see the mazik of ionic 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens on hybrid app. The longer list (and images) the more lag it has. As I can see you are using Ionic, try to use ion-list instead. It could help create a better list view.

p/s: sorry I was not able to made a comment (not enought rep point). So I post it here. Hope it help!

Two more suggestion:

- Use [angular bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) to reduce $watchers and faster render
- If you are building your app using ionic build for Android, you could use [built-in Crosswalk](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/) for a stronger webview of your app

Comment: please see this url http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/ 
ion-list also use ng-repeat to show the lists... so i dont think it will solve the issue... but i will try ion-list too... Thanks for your reply

Comment: yeah, list-view in hybrid is painful. Always try to reduce heavy load of listing. If ionic's propose could not help. You could try my new suggestion given in edited answer. Hope it help.